# Freebsd How to forward any classes IP?

Tags: sockets, unix, freebsd

I installed a FreeBSD 10.0 server(IP:10.1.2.3), and want to send packets to remote clients, with fake source ip, such as:

```
socket_sendto($socket $data, $length, 0, $ip, $port)
```

$data contains IP header, where i specify my "fake ip" here.

The questions is:

1. if i specify the IP to C class, everything goes well(below success):

   ```
   10.1.2.4
   10.1.3.5
   ```
2. if i specify the IP to B or A class, nothing send to destination(below failed):

   ```
   10.2.1.2
   11.1.2.3
   ```

So, how can i resolve the issue?

Btw i already modified sysctl.conf to :

```
  net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
  net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
  net.inet.ip.fastforwarding=1
```

Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 0):

May be related to routing (netmasks). If Your server IP is 10.1.2.3/16, all IP adresses like 10.1.X.Y are directly reachable, but if You try to send to IP addresses outside this range, IP packet goes via routers. Properly configured router should not pass such fake packets. You should check `defaultrouter` setting in `/etc/rc.conf`. This defaultrouter *may* receive such fake packets, unless something else is blocking them on Your FreeBSD machine.

Answer (score 0):

@Kestas is right, try the commands bellow:

1) Verify if you have route to the destination;

```
# netstat -ln
```

2) Test the connectivity:

```
# tracepath 10.2.1.2
```

3) Put on same network:

```
# ifconfig re0 10.2.1.1 / 255.0.0.0
```

GL !